# Cell content is cut off (vertically) when making boldface = because no longer completely top-aligned

Tags: excel, sharepoint

> This is when viewing the Excel inside the desktop browser version of
> Microsoft SharePoint. Not when opening inside the Excel software itself.

The following concerns a cell of which the content is cut off (vertically) when making the content boldface. This seems to be because there is no way to have it **completely** top-aligned (after making the text boldface, it seems to shift down a bit):

[image]

I tried to debug it with everything described in this support article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/fix-data-that-is-cut-off-in-cells-e996e213-6514-49d8-b82a-2721cef6144e but nothing worked.

What would be the most elegant workaround to prevent this please? I don't want to change the font-size.

Comment: I would change to middle-align.

Comment: @Isolated It doesn't solve the cut-off issue. Try it.

Comment: I'm having trouble replicating the issue, sorry. It works fine for me.

Comment: This is when viewing the Excel inside the desktop browser version of Microsoft SharePoint. Not when opening inside the Excel software itself.

Comment: Ah, ok. Not a user of that app.